# Using .equals() with Scanner object

Tags: java

For some reason I am getting different results from an input of lower case "y" than an input of upper case "Y". An input of "y" executes the code in the if statement but an input of "Y" does not.  Also, an input of "Y" does not execute the break; after else.  Why is this and what am I doing wrong?

```
Scanner playAgain = new Scanner (System.in);


System.out.println ("Play Again (Y/N)");

if ((playAgain.next().equals("y"))||(playAgain.next().equals("Y")))
{
Game theGame1 = new Game(0);
currentPts = currentPts + theGame1.play(total);

System.out.println("Current total is:" + "   "  +  currentPts);
}
else break;
```

Comment: You call next() twice when `Y` is typed - which means the stream will be read twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this condition:

```
if ((playAgain.next().equals("y"))||(playAgain.next().equals("Y")))
```

You're calling `playAgain.next()` *twice* - so it's fetching two different strings from the user.

I'm sure you only intended to fetch one string:

```
String answer = playAgain.next();
if (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y"))
```

Or alternatively, just use `equalsIgnoreCase`, which means you can just read once:

```
if (playAgain.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

Comment: Your solution solved the problem completely!  Thanks for teaching me equalsIgnoreCase, I'm sure it may come in handy in the future!

Answer (score 7):

You are reading two times in your if statement. So, your 2nd `playAgain.next()` is not reading the `"Y"`, if you enter a `"Y"`.

You can store the read input in a varaible, and use it instead:

```
String input = playAgain.next();   
if ((input.equals("y"))||(input.equals("Y")))
```

Apart from that, you can also use better `equalsIgnoreCase` method:

```
if (playAgain.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

Comment: @user2034570. Remember to mark one of the answers as accepted. That is how you mark the problem as solved. You need to mark the hollow arrow besides the answers to mark one as acceptd.